# unexpected result for inheritance in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am getting an unexpected result when trying to create a simple modification of the class KNeighborsClassifier:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

iris = load_iris()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris.data, iris.target, random_state=0)

class my_Classifier(KNeighborsClassifier):  
  """My Nearest Neighbour classifier"""
  def __init__(self, gamma=0):
    def my_dist(x, y):  # squared distance
      return np.sum((abs(x-y))**gamma)
    KNeighborsClassifier.__init__(self, n_neighbors=1, metric=my_dist)
    self.gamma = gamma
    print(gamma)
  def fit(self, X, y):
    KNeighborsClassifier.fit(self, X, y)
    return self
  def predict(self, X, y=None):
    return KNeighborsClassifier.predict(self, X)
  def score(self, X, y):
    return KNeighborsClassifier.score(self, X, y)
```

I have made the metric dependent on a parameter gamma>=0.  If gamma=2, this is just the squared Euclidean metric, and if gamma=0, this is a useless metric (essentially a constant).  First it works as expected: for

```
knn = my_Classifier(gamma=2)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
knn.score(X_test,y_test)
```

the output is

```
2
0.9736842105263158
```

(the accuracy is good) and for

```
knn = my_Classifier(gamma=0)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
knn.score(X_test,y_test)
```

the output is

```
0
0.34210526315789475
```

(the accuracy is hopeless).  I am also printing the value of gamma used.

However, when I try

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
param_grid = {'gamma': [0,2]}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(my_Classifier(), param_grid)
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
grid_search.score(X_test, y_test)
```

the result is unexpected:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0.34210526315789475
```

Why is the value gamma=0 used every time?  And gamma=2 (producing a much better result) is never tried.  I know I am making some silly mistake but can't see where.

Answer (score 0):

**The value gamma = 0 is not used every time !**

What you see when you get this:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0.34210526315789475
```

**Is the `score`**

---

To see the `gamma` use this:

```
grid_search.cv_results_
```

Comment: Thank you, but my question is why the score is so poor, it should be 97% rather than 34%.  My understanding is that the 0s printed out are the values of gamma used in the process of grid search.  The command grid_search.cv_results_ produces the right values for gamma (0 and 2) but all scores correspond to gamma=0.